# Change default Emmet settings in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Is it possible to change **default** (not for single project) Emmet behaviour for command `!` in Visual Studio Code?

For example, I don't want to see the attribule `lang="en"` in `<html>` tag? Also I don't want to see the string:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And maybe I will want to add some another strings to default Emmet-behaviour in VS Code.

Comment: you can edit the emmet config file, but you have to do it every update of VSC. Easier is to make a snippet with the lines you want

Comment: Hmm, went to ask this same question, and this answer was the first "Similar Question".  "Brilliant!" I thought.  Except there's no answer.  Can this really not be done?  Seems like it'd be a fairly basic thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

According to official [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets) you can add or overwrite the contents of default Emmet snippets in VS Code with custom ones. Here how you can do it:

1. Firstly you need to create to the snippets.json file and set the path to it in user settings.

   ```
    "emmet.extensionsPath": "C:\\Users\\Folder\\snippets.json"
   ```
2. Then you should figure out which snippet to change, see default [HTML snippets](https://github.com/emmetio/snippets/blob/master/html.json) and [CSS snippets](https://github.com/emmetio/snippets/blob/master/css.json).
3. Finally overwrite the snippet in snippets.json. For example:

[image: emmet-snippet]

Hopefully it will help you solve your issue! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the defaults (see [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets)). In your case:

1. Create a `snippets.json` (must use this filename), e.g. at `~/.vs-emmet/snippets.json`
2. Search in VS Code `File -> Preferences -> Settings` for "Emmet: Extension Path" and add the path to the directory of `snippets.json`, e.g. `~/.vs-emmet`
3. Insert this into `snippets.json`:

```json
{
  "html": {
    "snippets": {
      "doc": "html>(head>meta[charset=${charset}]+title{${1:Document}})+body"
    }
  }
}
```

This replaces the `doc`-abbreviation with a leaner boilerplate. `doc` is used in the `!`-abbreviation. So `!` now creates this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

4. Refer to the [official emmet documentation](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/) and the [default HTML snippets](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/snippets/html.json) to make further adjustments.