# How can I set custom code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

in an empty HTML file in VS Code, with "!" I can insert this default code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>  
</body>
```

But am I able to change this default to an own text for every new HTML file? Thank you

Comment: just define a user snippet with the required content, that is the easiest way to keep it when you update, I think it is `!` not `/`

Comment: you can use the extension: [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates) to define default content for HTML files with snippets and variables

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247129/change-default-emmet-settings-in-vs-code) help?

Comment: Thank you guys! Yes, this will help me!